InfiniteScroll component from react js not firing next function
In the following component we show the messages when loading the page for the first time using the useEffect (fetchData), and theoretically when scrolling to the end of the page it would have to trigger the fetchMoreData function, but it doesn't work.
With the fetchData function it loads the first 10 posts (page 1) but the next prop of the InfiniteScroll component that should load the following pages does not fire, and it would have to do it asynchronously.
REPO: https://github.com/Devansh-365/ceddit/blob/main/client/src/components/post/posts.jsx
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import InfiniteScroll from "react-infinite-scroll-component";
import { Stack } from "@chakra-ui/react";
import { PostLoading } from "./post-loading";
import PostItem from "./post-item";
import { getPosts } from "../../api/posts";
import { BASE_URL } from "../../config";

export const Posts = ({ posts, setPosts, sortType}) => {
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
  const [hasMore, setHasMore] = useState(true);
  const [index, setIndex] = useState(2);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await fetch(`${BASE_URL}api/posts/page/1`);
        const data = await response.json();
        setItems(data);
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    };

    fetchData();
  }, []);

  const fetchMoreData = async () => {
    await fetch(`${BASE_URL}api/posts/page/${index}`)
      .then(async (res) => {
        const data = await res.json();
        setItems((prevItems) => [...prevItems, ...data]);

        data.length > 0 ? setHasMore(true) : setHasMore(false);
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));

    setIndex((prevIndex) => prevIndex + 1);
  };

  const fetchSortedData = async () => {
    await fetch(`${BASE_URL}api/posts/page/${index}`)
      .then(async (res) => {
        const data = await res.json();

        let sortedPosts;
        switch (sortType) {
          case "createdAt":
            sortedPosts = [...data].sort(
              (a, b) => new Date(b.createdAt) - new Date(a.createdAt)
            );
            break;
          case "upvotedBy":
            sortedPosts = [...data].sort((a, b) => {
              const aUpvotes = Array.isArray(a.upvotedBy)
                ? a.upvotedBy.length
                : 0;
              const bUpvotes = Array.isArray(b.upvotedBy)
                ? b.upvotedBy.length
                : 0;
              return bUpvotes - aUpvotes;
            });
            break;
          case "commentCount":
            sortedPosts = [...data].sort((a, b) => {
              const aComments =
                typeof a.commentCount === "number" ? a.commentCount : 0;
              const bComments =
                typeof b.commentCount === "number" ? b.commentCount : 0;
              return bComments - aComments;
            });
            break;
          default:
            // sortedPosts = data;
        }

        setPosts((prevItems) => [...prevItems, ...sortedPosts]);

        data.length > 0 ? setHasMore(true) : setHasMore(false);
      })
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));

    setIndex((prevIndex) => prevIndex + 1);
  }
  

  return (
    <>
      {
        posts ? (
          <InfiniteScroll
            dataLength={posts.length}
            next={fetchSortedData}
            hasMore={hasMore}
            loader={<PostLoading />}
          >
            <Stack>
              {posts.map((item, i) => (
                <PostItem post={item} key={i} />
              ))}
            </Stack>
          </InfiniteScroll>
        )
          : (
            items.length === 0 ? (
              <PostLoading />
            ) : (
              <InfiniteScroll
                dataLength={items.length}
                next={fetchMoreData}
                hasMore={hasMore}
                loader={<PostLoading />}
              >
                <Stack>
                  {items.map((item, i) => (
                    <PostItem post={item} key={i} />
                  ))}
                </Stack>
              </InfiniteScroll>
            )

          )
      }
    </>
  );
};

